# Compiling error: Login and Menu

Tags: c++, algorithm, authentication, menu

So im getting a compiling error that says:
12 C:\Dev-Cpp\login.cpp expected unqualified-id before "while" 
12 C:\Dev-Cpp\login.cpp expected `,' or`;' before "while" 
 C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [login.o] Error 1

this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string username;
string password;
int attemptCount = 0;
}
while ( attemptCount < 3 )
{
cout << "Enter your username: " << endl;
cin >> username;
cout << "Enter your password: " << endl;
cin >> password;

if ( username != "Invitado" && password != "abel" )

{
int choice;
bool gameOn = true;
while (gameOn != false){
cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
cout << " 1 - Inicia el juego.\n\n";
cout << " 2 - Modo Historia.\n\n";
cout << " 3 - Ayuda.\n\n";
cout << " 4 - Salir.\n\n";
    cout << "\n\n\nElige tu opcion\n\n\n ";

cin >> choice;

switch (choice)
{
case 1:
cout << "\n\n\n\nBienvenido al juego...!\n";
// rest of code here
break;
case 2:
cout << "\n\n\n Este es el progreso hasta el momento\n";
// rest of code here
break;
case 3:
cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nPara ayuda, por favor visite www.blabla.com!\n";
// rest of code here
break;
case 4:
cout << "\n\n\nFin del programa.\n";
gameOn = false;
break;
default:
cout << "\n\n\nNo es una opcion valida. \n";
cout << "\n\n\nElige de nuevo.\n";
cin >> choice;
break;
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: u have an accidental } on the fourth line of `main` in `int attemptCount = 0;
}
while ( attemptCount < 3 )`

Comment: This is the reason I would give my students for why indenting is important.

Comment: Why's this tagged algorithm?